# Input a string with a comparison operator and perform the comparison on an array index

Tags: python, python-3.x

So here's my code so far:

```
# Function to search for possible matches for words: and chapters:
def intSearch(term, row, index):
    """
    Index of 6: Word search
    Index of 7: Chapter search
    """
    rowValue = row[index]
    if True:
        return True
    return False
```

The 'if True' is just temporary. So what I want is for the term input to be a comparison operator then a integer, for example '>=334'. Then this string can be broken down and compared to the specific index of the row which I can use row[index] for. If this comparison is correct, it'll return True and if not, it'll return False. The comparison should work for basically all operators including: ==, !=, >, <, <=, >= and for a range.

So the comparison will basically look like:

```
if row[index] >= term:
```

Where row[index] is array integer, >= is the comparison operator and term is the number you want to compare on.

I could use alot of if and else statements although I'm not sure how efficient that would be.

Hope I made this clear. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to manage several conditions, then if-elif-else is the right choice. Unlike other languages, Python does not support switch-case statements which are better suited for complex case-based execution.

Comment: Just not sure how efficient that would be if I have to test for each operator

Comment: Don’t prematurely optimise your code, get it working first, test it, then if it is slow identify the problems. Better to have something slow which works than no code at all :)

Comment: So the function just compares one item to the given term? You can just do `return row[index] >= term`. Sorry if I'm understanding wrong, is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two very useful concepts for this type of problem, the standard `operator` library and a standard `dictionary`.

Example:

```
import operator as op

op_map = {
    "==": op.eq,
    "!=": op.ne,
    ">": op.gt,
    "<": op.lt,
    "<=": op.le,
    ">=": op.ge,
}

x = 10
y = 0

for op_str in op_map:
    print(f"{x} {op_str} {y}: {op_map[op_str](x, y)}")
```

Output:

```
10 == 0: False
10 != 0: True
10 > 0: True
10 < 0: False
10 <= 0: False
10 >= 0: True
```